# How do I configure a vnc server which supports xkeyboard extention?

Tags: server, vnc, qt

I am logging into an Ubuntu 14.04 remote machine with a VNC server.
I am using some Python IDE programs which use Qt, but while running them I am getting the error:

```
Qt: XKEYBOARD extension not present on the X server.
```

1. Is there a VNC server which supports `xkeyboard`?
2. How can I configure an appropriate `xkeyboard` on my VNC server?

Comment: If there's a simple way I can test it for you, I can let you know it if works through x11vnc - I suspect it would. I found out how to test for it. I'll stick it in an answer.

Answer (score -3):

**x11vnc**

From within an x11vnc session, we can test for XKEYBOARD by running the following in a terminal window:

```
xdpyinfo -ext XKEYBOARD | tail -2
```

In 17.10, this results in:

```
XKEYBOARD version 1.0 opcode: 135, base event: 85, base error: 137
```

Which indicates the X server has the version 1.0 of the XKEYBOARD extension enabled.

Note: This is on XOrg, not Wayland.